# EditText how to allow input from Gboard through voice only and disable input by typing?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText where I want to allow user input by voice only and I want to disable input by typing through the keyoard, like image below in the end.

In EditText there is no option as

```
android:inputType="voice"
```

Then I tried,

```
editText.setEnabled(false);
```

This one disabled any input from the Keyboard.

Then I tried

```
editText.setFocusable(false)
```

It's not working.

Then I thought of trying through keycode like below,

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KEYCODE_VOICE_ASSIST){
                    Log.d("Debug", "Voice Search is Enabled");
                    editText.setEnabled(true);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    editText.setEnabled(false);
                    return  false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Since I am not getting the log , it seems KEYCODE_VOICE_ASSIST is not the appropriate one to recognize voice input.

Any other suggestion will be appreciated.

My xml,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    tools:context=".activity.VoiceSearchActivity">
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:hint="@string/voice_input"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorLightBlack"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorDimGray"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:background="@drawable/voice_add_btn"
        android:text="@string/add" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: use `digits` and set it as empty to your edittext

Comment: disable the keyboard at all, and add a button to start voice recognition. And use voice recognition.

Comment: @RahulKhurana modify my code if I am wrong inside Edittext I am doing inside Edittext xml ````android:digits="123456789" ```` and inside java class ````edittext.setKeyListener(null); ````. This is is disabling the input but once keyboard pops up the voice icon is missing.

Comment: put your xml code in the question

Comment: @RahulKhurana Check the edited code.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Yes I tried using voice recognition , In that to allow multiple input user has to press the voice icon again and again , my client liked the idea of Gboard more , because it will allow user to speak multiple words together without pressing again and again.